# Need Page refresh each time Save method called

Tags: controller, commandbutton, commandlink, refresh, method

I have to refresh the page each time the Save method is called. Please find my page and code snippet here. Can someone help me here?

Page :

```
<apex:commandLink value="Save" action="{!savei}" target="_parent" styleClass="btn" style="text-decoration:none;padding:4px;" rendered="{!Incident_abv__c.Confirm_Attestation_abv__c == false}" reRender="pb1,pb2"  id="theButton"/>
```

Controller :

```
public pagereference savei()
    {
    oIncTranListGEN = new List<Incident_Transaction_Line_Item_abv__c>();
      oIncTranListGEN.addAll(oIncTranListHCPDetail );
   oIncTranListGEN.addAll(oIncTranListHCI );
   oIncTranListGEN.addAll(oIncTranListPharmacy);
   oIncTranListGEN.addAll(oIncTranListHCPSamples);
   oIncTranListGEN.addAll(oIncTranListHCPSpeaker);
   System.debug('Spandan List$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$'+oIncTranListGEN);
   update oIncTranListGEN;


   update oIncTranListSynch;

    System.debug('Spandan List$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$'+oIncTranList);
    ApexPages.Message msg = new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.INFO, 'New values saved');
    ApexPages.addMessage(msg);

    return null;
    }
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: as of now `reRender="pb1,pb2"` rerenders these sections or not? Do you want the whole page to refresh instead of these sections alone?

Comment: I want the whole page to refresh whenever Save method is called.

Comment: then try removing that `reRender` parameter. Does that help?

Comment: Hi AslamK! Not working

Comment: Can you give ID to page tag in VF and rerender it ? reRender="pageId"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi friends I would like to share my answer I got here. In the constructor showing this portion.

```
if(ApexPages.CurrentPage().getparameters().get('Saved') == 'Success')
{
    ApexPages.addMessage(
        new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.INFO, 'Successfully Saved'));
    ApexPages.CurrentPage().getparameters().put('Saved','');
}
```

Then in Save method make a new link and redirect it there.

```
    nextlink = '/apex/AttestIncident?Id=' + recId + '&Saved=Success';

    PageReference nextPage = new PageReference(nextlink);
    nextPage.setRedirect(true);
```

And return to the nextpage. This function works fine for me. Thanks All.